# How to split a single line of text after n words + style separately?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a single line of text which is the post title and it looks like this:

```
<h2 class="title">
  <a href="http://example.com">Report 10/2019 The name of the report</a>
</h2>
```

I'd like to be able to:
a) split the name of the link title after the year;
b) style separately the "Report 10/2019" and the rest of the name in two different ways (preferable adding a class to each part - or at least the first part).

I managed to split the text using this:

```
var breakAt = 17;
var brokenString = $(".title a").html();
brokenString = brokenString.substring(0, breakAt) + "<br>" + brokenString.substring(breakAt);
$(".title a").html(brokenString);
```

But this divides the name by number of characters, whereas it would be safer to split after X number of spaces (in this case after second space) - the number of the month will be one character or two.
And don't know how to apply different styling to the two parts of the title link.

Comment: Is your string static or having fixed words?

Comment: Instead of looking for spaces, I’d rather match the pattern of `Report mm/yyyy` with a small regular expression, and then just wrap that into a span.

Comment: Another approach:
where is the `html` generated (Serverside template)? Is it possible to edit this? So you can extend it and set additional CSS classes.

Comment: Chris - it's poor form to not respond to answers people take the time to write for you. In the least please upvote some and comment and, if any solves your problem, accept. Remember we do this to help you.

Comment: I'm sorry - not yet enough experience here. Thanks. I've managed to make it work as commented below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57161267/5481723

Comment: Cool, glad you got it sorted. It would still be a courtesy to upvote the answers that people provided (assuming they were useful), even if they weren't directly the one that led you to the answer. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over all the titles, get their content, apply a regular expression and wrap the substring from the beginning to the year (4 digits) into a `span` (or another element if you prefer)

Then apply a style to the `span` (e.g a bolder font and `display: block`) so the remaining part starts on a new line)

```js
var titles = document.querySelectorAll('.title a');
[...titles].forEach((title) => {
   var content = title.textContent;
   content = content.replace(/(^.+?\d{4})/, '<span>$1</span>');
   title.innerHTML = content;
})
```

```css
.title a {
  color: #333;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.title span {
  font-weight: 700;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="title">
  <a href="http://example.com">Report 10/2019 The name of the report</a>
</h2>
<h2 class="title">
  <a href="http://example.com">Another Report 3 / 2019 The name of the report</a>
</h2>
```

Comment: This worked well. To add the line break and add a class to style the report number I changed `content = content.replace(/(^.+?\d{4})/, '<span>$1</span>');` to `content = content.replace(/(^.+?\d{4})/, '<div class="extra-class">$1</div>');`

Comment: You can't insert a block element into an inline element.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using split function and second space from string:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var string = $('.title a').text();
    var report_date  = string.split(' ').slice(0, 2).join(' ');
    var report_title  = string.replace(report_date, '').trim();      
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's two key things you need:

- RegExp, for better and more dynamic pattern matching
- `span` tags, since you want to add classes (you can't do this if you just split the two parts with a `br` - they're still just text nodes)

So, the question for the RegExp is, how do we define the breakpoint? Well, it seems sensible to use the datestamp for that. First we'll grab it:

```
let a = $(".title a"),
let part_1 = a.text().match(/^.+\d{2}\/\d{4}/);
```

Then we need to remove what we just matched from the overall string, to give us the second part. We'll also remove the whitespace between the two parts.

```
let part_2 = a.text().replace(part_1[0], '').trim();
```

The last thing is to put these two parts into `span` tags inside the `a`.

```
$('<span>').addClass('part-1').text(part_1[0]).appendTo(a);
$('<span>').addClass('part-2').text(part_2).appendTo(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use regular expression, since the length of the first part of the string might be dynamic. This pattern should do the work of splitting your string into two parts: one with the report + month/year, and the other with the report name:

```
/^(.*?\/\d{4})(.*?)$/
```

See proof-of-concept here:

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll('h2.title a');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(links, (link) => {
  const textRegex = /^(.*?\/\d{4})(.*?)$/gi;
  const matches = textRegex.exec(link.textContent);
  const reportYear = matches[1].trim();
  const reportName = matches[2].trim();
  
  link.innerHTML = `<span class="year">${reportYear}</span><span class="name">${reportName}</span>`;
});
```

```css
.title a span {
  display: block;
}
.year {
  color: red;
}
.name {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="title">
  <a href="http://example.com">Report 10/2019 The name of the report</a>
</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to break the string based on the number of spaces, you can use `split`.

Here is an example:

```js
var stringToBreak = $(".title a").html();
var brokenArr = stringToBreak.split(' ');
var txtToStyle1 = brokenArr.slice(0, 2).join(' ');
var txtToStyle2 = brokenArr.slice(2).join(' ');
$(".title a").empty();
$(".title a").append(
  $("<span>").html(txtToStyle1).css('color', 'red')
).append(
  $("<span>").html(' ' + txtToStyle2)
);
```

```css
a {
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="title">
  <a href="http://example.com">Report 10/2019 The name of the report</a>
</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution.

```
var brokenString = $(".title a").html();
var stringArray = brokenString.split(" ");
var firstPart = stringArray[0] + " " + stringArray[1];

// firsPart delete from array

stringArray.shift();
stringArray.shift();

// now assign in html

$(".title a").html(firstPart + ' <br>' + stringArray.join(' '));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const anchorText = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].innerText;
const splitBy = '2019 ';
const splittedText = anchorText.split(splitBy);
const firstElement = "<span class='first'>" + splittedText[0] + splitBy + "</span>";
const secondElement = "<span class='second'>" + splittedText[1] + "</span>";
document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].innerHTML = firstElement + secondElement;
```

```css
.first {
  color: red;
}

.second {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="title">
  <a href="http://example.com">Report 10/2019 The name of the report</a>
</h2>
```

If 2019 it's a dynamical value like (current year) you can retrieve that from the `new Date()` date object and add it there.